# TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, jestjs

Our build environment currently uses node 12.19.0 and npm 6.14.8.  When I saw that the new LTS version of node 14.15.1 (still npm 6.14.8) was available I downloaded it and ran our webpack build script and received this error.  Is the new version of node complaining about an error that was always there, but ignored by 12.19.0?

```
internal/fs/utils.js:781
  throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE(
  ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received an instance of XMLElement
    at writeFile (fs.js:1436:5)
    at go$writeFile (/Components/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:131:14)
    at Object.writeFile (/Components/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:128:12)
    at /Components/node_modules/jest-html-reporter/dist/main.js:47:13
    at /Components/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:48:26
    at callback (/Components/node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:295:20)
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:184:5) {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}
```

Comment: We're seeing the same error, except in our case it's objecting to an Array rather than an XMLElement. And we're calling writeFileSync() rather than writeFile().

Comment: any update on this issue, i am using latest node 15

Comment: any new update on this?

Answer (score 2):

Add a second argument to writeFileSync

Instead of:

```
fs.writeFileSync(`${folderName}/styles.css`);
```

Do this:-

```
fs.writeFileSync(`${folderName}/styles.css`, '');
```

It tells wfs what to write to the file. It can be left empty

Answer (score 2):

Uplift jest-html-reporter version to at least 3.1.3